# What would be the size of a single table's schema data (meta-data) in a DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-design

Assume my SQL server DB is installed in a 1 GB HDD.
Now that I'm creating tables with a infinite loop in that DB but not adding any rows to any of the table. After how many tables will my DB (of 1 GB space limit) will get out of space limit and interrupts the loop.

Comment: You're asking two very different questions here. SQL Server will try to allocate additional hard disk space well before its current data file is filled with actual data.

Comment: Try it and let us know what comes out :)

Comment: Don't know how much it would actually be but it will greatly depend how long you object names are, how many columns it has and the length of thier names. The number of constraints and thier name lenghts.

Comment: This question doesn't have a real answer. You installed SQL Server on a 1 GB drive? Really? Or are you saying you have a second drive that is 1GB that is empty? And of course the only real answer is "who cares". Way more tables than any realistic database would need. You will actually run into an error long before you run out of disc space because the total number objects can not exceed 2,147,483,647 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn205318.aspx)

```
table_size = (size of each index added together) + (row size * row count)
```

So for a table with no rows or records, the answer is not a lot of space, so large amounts of tables can be created

Comment: my actual requirement to know the sizeof information of metadata of each table without the data in its rows...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a few things; 
How many columns are you adding to each table? Each column name can be up to 128 bytes. Type info (system_type_id, user_type_id) and object_id will take some bytes too.

Do you run with Trace flag 1117 and/or 1118?
If so, the table is assigned a 64 kB extent instead of an 8 kB page. EDIT: This is not allocated when the table is created, only when the first row is added. If all rows are deleted, the first page/extent still "belongs" to the table.

Do you add any index? If yes, then there will be rows in sys.indexes.

Are your tables partitioned? then Lots of bytes are added.